# Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file for architecture arm64 on M1 with a framework built for arm64 only

Tags: xcode, linker, frameworks, arm64, podfile

I'm adding an SDK to my react native project. This SDK is compiled for arm64 only. It runs fine on a real device, but when I run on a simulator, I get:

Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file for architecture arm64

What I don't understand is, since I'm using M1, and the SDK is compiled for arm64, why would I get this error? Isn't XCode 14.2 simulator supposed to support both arm64 & x86_64? So is there anything explicit that I've to set to simulator to allow it to run in arm64 mode?

lipo -info xx.framework/xx
Non-fat file: xx.framework/xx is architecture: arm64

MacOS Monterey 12.6
XCode 14.2 (natively non-Rosetta)
Macbook Pro M1

Comment: Platform and architecture are two different things. If you only have arm64-iOS binaries, then you can only target arm64-iOS. If you do have arm64-iOSSimulator binaries, then you should be able to build an xcframework somehow, but I've never done that. You can't have a regular framework/binary with two arm64 slices though due to limitations of the Mach-O file format.